# Retain all multi-selected values in an option-select dropdown on form submit

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a multi-select dropdown menu from [here](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/).
The `<option>` values are dynamically populated with SQL data which works fine. However on the form refresh, I'm only able to retain the last selected value out of a multi select and others selected earlier disappears.

Can that be fixed?

```
<select name="m_type" id="m_type" class="selectpicker form-control" title="Merchandiser type" multiple>
            <?php 
               $SQL="SELECT * FROM usertypes";
               $run=mysqli_query($db,$SQL) or die ("SQL Error");

               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run))
                 { ?>
                  <option value='<?php echo $row['merch_types']; ?>' <?php echo (isset($_POST['m_type']) && $_POST['m_type'] == $row['merch_types'])?'selected="selected"':''; ?>><?php echo $row['merch_types']; ?></option>
                 <?php } ?>

</select>
```

Comment: Change `name="m_type"` to `name="m_type[]"`

Comment: @SougataBose I can convert **m_type** in to an array like you say. How do you suggest I retain the total array value on form submission in side the php snippet? (I've edited couple of lines of `<option>` tag)

Comment: You can store them into an array variable when posted.

Comment: Sorry, not being able to figure it out @SougataBose :(